# Redux/ngRx with Angular4 initial state incorrectly being modified

Tags: angular, redux, state, ngrx

I am currently implementing ngRx state management into my Angular4 application but so far I am having issues where when I go to clear some form filters in the store the 'initial state' object I use to clear the values and reset the state seems to have property values set in it. This should obviously remain untouched as it is an object used to instantiate the state and then not be touched again.

Here is some of my code. Please note this is rough at the moment so long if/else statements etc are to be refactored later.

Controller:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'report-exceptions',
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: '/app/views/reports/report-exceptions.component.html'
})

export class ReportExceptionsComponent {
    @ViewChild('f') form;
    private filtersDropDown: Boolean;
    private formModel: ReportExceptionFilters;
    private formDefaults: Object;
    private viewState = {
        reportExceptionsLoaded: false
    };
    reportExceptions: Array<ReportException> = [];


    constructor(
        private _vehicleService: VehicleService,
        private _accountsService: AccountService,
        private _reportExceptionService: ReportExceptionService,
        private _authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
        private _damageService: DamageService,
        private _boothService: BoothService,
        private _userService: UserService,
        private _store: Store<GlobalState>
    ) {

        this._store.select(store => store.reportExceptionReducer)
            .subscribe((response) => {
                this.formDefaults = response.formDefaults;
                this.formModel = response.formModel;
                this.reportExceptions = response.reportExceptions;
                this.filtersDropDown = response.filtersDropDown;

                if(!this._authenticationService.isSuper()) {
                    this.formModel.accountId = this._authenticationService.accountId;
                }

                if(!this.formDefaults.accounts.length) {
                    this.getAccounts();
                }

                if(this.checkAccountSelected()) {
                    this.getMarques();
                }

                if(this.checkMarqueSelected()) {
                    this.getModels();
                }
            });
    }

    getAccounts() {
        this._accountsService.getAccounts({})return Object.assign({}, state, { formModel: initialState.formModel });
            .subscribe((response) => {
                    this._store.dispatch({ type: 'POPULATE_FORM_DEFAULTS', payload: { ...this.formDefaults, accounts: formHelper.addSelectOption(response.extras.Accounts, 'Name', 'AccountId') }});
                    //this.formDefaults.accounts = formHelper.addSelectOption(response.extras.Accounts, 'Name', 'AccountId');
                },
                (error) => {
                    this._accountsService.processResponseError(error);
                });
    }

    getMarques() {
        this._vehicleService.getMarques({})
        .subscribe((response) => {
                this._store.dispatch({ type: 'POPULATE_FORM_DEFAULTS', payload: {...this.formDefaults, marques: formHelper.addSelectOption(response.extras.Data, 'Name', 'MarqueId') }});
                //this.formDefaults.marques = formHelper.addSelectOption(response.extras.Data, 'Name', 'MarqueId');
            },
            (error) => {
                this._accountsService.processResponseError(error);
            });
    }

    getModels() {
        this._vehicleService.getModels({})
            .subscribe((response) => {
                    this._store.dispatch({ type: 'POPULATE_FORM_DEFAULTS', payload: {...this.formDefaults, models: formHelper.addSelectOption(response.extras.Data, 'Description', 'ModelId') }});
                    //this.formDefaults.models = formHelper.addSelectOption(response.extras.Data, 'Description', 'ModelId');
                },
                (error) => {
                    this._accountsService.processResponseError(error);
                });
    }

    runReports() {
        this.viewState.reportExceptionsLoaded = false;
        const FromDate = this.formModel.dateFrom !== null && this.formModel.timeFrom !== null ? timeHelper.convertToDateTime(this.formModel.dateFrom , this.formModel.timeFrom) : null;
        const ToDate = this.formModel.dateTo !== null && this.formModel.timeTo !== null ? timeHelper.convertToDateTime(this.formModel.dateTo , this.formModel.timeTo) : null;

        this._reportExceptionService.getReportExceptions({
            ReportExceptions: [],
            Criteria: {
                AccountId: this.formModel.accountId,
                VehicleId: this.formModel.vehicleId,
                MakeId: this.formModel.makeId,
                ModelId: this.formModel.modelId,
                //Limit: 5,
                SortBy: 'DESC',
                FromDate,
                ToDate,
                DamageCode: this.formModel.damageCode,
                DamageLocation: this.formModel.damageLocation,
                DamageSeverity: this.formModel.damageSeverities
            }
        })
        .subscribe((response) => {
            this.viewState.reportExceptionsLoaded = true;
            this._store.dispatch({ type: 'POPULATE_REPORT_EXCEPTIONS', payload: { reportExceptions: response.extras.ReportExceptions }});
            this._store.dispatch({ type: 'POPULATE_FILTERS', payload: { formModel: this.formModel }});

            this.viewState.reportExceptionsLoading = true;
        },
        (error) => {
            this._accountsService.processResponseError(error);
        });
    }

    private clearForm() {
        this._store.dispatch({ type: 'RESET_REPORT_EXCEPTIONS' });
        this._store.dispatch({ type: 'CLEAR_FILTERS' });
        this._store.dispatch({ type: 'CLEAR_FORM_DEFAULTS' });
        if(!this._authenticationService.isSuper()) {
            this.formModel.accountId = this._authenticationService.accountId;
        }
        this.form.form.markAsPristine();
        this.form.form.markAsUntouched();
        this.form.form.updateValueAndValidity();

    }

    private toggleFiltersDropdown() {
        this._store.dispatch({ type: 'TOGGLE_FILTER_DROPDOWN', payload: { filtersDropDown: this.filtersDropDown }})
    }

    private checkAccountSelected(): boolean {
        // Check accountId is selected and there are accounts in the form defaults
        if((this.formModel.accountId) && ((undefined !== typeof this.formDefaults.accounts) && (this.formDefaults.accounts.length))) {
            // Check that no marque is currently set and that marques form defaults aren't set
            if((!this.formModel.marqueId) && ((undefined !== this.formDefaults.marques) && (this.formDefaults.marques.length == 0))) {
                return true
            }
        }
    }

    private checkMarqueSelected(): boolean {
        // Check marque is selected and there are marques in the form defaults
        if((this.formModel.marqueId) && ((undefined !== typeof this.formDefaults.marques) && (this.formDefaults.marques.length))) {
            // Check that no model is currently set and that models form defaults aren't set
            if((!this.formModel.modelId) && ((undefined !== this.formDefaults.models) && (this.formDefaults.models.length == 0))) {
                return true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Reducer:

```
import { Action, ActionReducer } from "@ngrx/store";
import { ReportExceptionState } from "../interfaces/AppState";
import {User} from "../../classes-and-types/users/User.type";

const initialState: ReportExceptionState = {
    reportExceptions: [],
    selectedReportException: null,
    formModel: {
        vehicleId: null,
        marqueId: null,
        model: null,
        location: null,
        damageCode: null,
        damageLocation: null,
        damageSeverity: null,
        accountId: null,
        user: null,
        dateFrom: null,
        dateTo: null,
        timeFrom: null,
        timeTo: null
    },
    formDefaults: {
        vehicleId: null as string,
        marques: [] as Array<any>,
        models: [] as Array<any>,
        locations:[] as Array<any>,
        damageCodes: [] as Array<any>,
        damageLocations:[] as Array<any>,
        damageSeverities:[] as Array<any>,
        accounts: [] as Array<any>,
        users: [] as Array<User>,
        dateFrom: Date,
        dateTo: Date,
        timeFrom: null as string,
        timeTo: null as string
    },
    filtersDropDown: false
};

export const reportExceptionReducer = (state = initialState, action: Action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'POPULATE_REPORT_EXCEPTIONS' : {
            return Object.assign({}, state, action.payload);
        }
        case 'RESET_REPORT_EXCEPTIONS' : {
            return Object.assign({}, state, { reportExceptions: initialState.reportExceptions });
        }
        case 'POPULATE_FORM_DEFAULTS' : {
            return Object.assign({}, state, { formDefaults: action.payload });
        }
        case 'CLEAR_FORM_DEFAULTS' : {
            return Object.assign({}, state, { formDefaults: initialState.formDefaults });
        }
        case 'POPULATE_FILTERS' : {
            return Object.assign({}, state, action.payload )
        }
        case 'CLEAR_FILTERS' : {
            return Object.assign({}, state, { formModel: initialState.formModel });
        }
        case 'TOGGLE_FILTER_DROPDOWN' : {
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                filtersDropDown: !action.payload.filtersDropDown
            });
        }
        default: {
            return state;
        }
    }
};
```

As you can see for example, in my 'CLEAR_FILTERS' switch option I reset the state formModel back to the initial state using the following piece of code:

```
return Object.assign({}, state, { formModel: initialState.formModel });
```

Which is resetting the 'formModel' property back to that of the initial state. Only thing is, when I put a breakpoint in here it would seem that the initialState Object has been modified?! Can anyone see why my initialState object is holding values when it shouldn't be?

Thanks

Comment: What is the question? SO is there to help other developers too. It is not clear what you're asking. Please rephrase the subject of your post.